# SQL- Select and Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to have a query that will get the subject that has "cs", "cp", "is" in code column. what query will i use ?

sample table

```
Subject | Code
1 | cs
1 | cp
1 | is
2 | cp
2 | cs
3 | cs
3 | cp
3 | is
4 | cp
```

so the output must be

```
subject
1
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select subject
from t
where code in ('cp', 'cs', 'is')
group by subject
having count(distinct code) = 3;
```